# How to create vectors of constructs created by parsers

Tags: scala, parsing

So im trying to create a parser and this is one of the production rules :

```
app : app "(" ((exp ",")* exp)? ")"
```

And the case class for this looks like :

```
 case class AppExp(fn : Expression, args : Vector[Expression])
```

The main thing thats tripping me up is the `Vector[Expression]`. How do I make it so the parser returns that?

Ive tried to convert the production:

```
 lazy val app : PackratParser[Expression] =
   app ~ ("(" ~> opt(rep(exp <~ ",") ~> exp) <~ ")") ^^ { case e ~ t => AppExp (e, t) }
```

But the `opt` part makes it so the returns an `Option` instead of A `Vector`.

```
found:Option[...]
required:Vector[...]
And it points to the `t` in `AppExp(e, t)` in the error message.
```

I hope im explaining myself clear. What makes a `Vector` of, well Expressions in this case, but in general? Because in some other case classes, they also require a Vector of Expressions I dont know what that entails. Am I even doing anything right? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `opt(rep(foo <~ separator) ~ foo)` seems to accept the same as `repsep(foo, separator)`, and the `repsep` gizmo returns a `List`, which is almost the same as a `Vector`. So, why not just take `repsep`?

Comment: ...and why is it `opt(rep(exp <~ ",") ~> exp` in the first place? Do you really want to throw away all but the very last expression? If not, then you shouldn't use `~>`, use `~` instead.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yeah that `~>` was a mistake. Im still grasping the concepts of all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `opt(rep(exp <~ ",") ~> exp)` construct is way too complicated, and it throws away all but the very last expression. Use `repsep(exp, ",")` instead.